# Detection of overflow

Tags: c++, char, overflow, unsigned

How to detect overflow of unsigned char variable in c++?

Comment: Well first of all, an `unsigned char` ranges from 0 to 255, and youve assigned it 260.

Comment: Compiled with default settings, gcc and g++ will issue a `warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use braces to initialize your value to force a compile-time error (assuming you use C++11 or later):

```
unsigned char Test{260};
```

Brace-initialization doesn't allow narrowing conversions.

Of course, that still wouldn't allow sticking the value 260 into an `unsigned char` but it would draw attention to the attempt. You'd need a bigger data type, e.g., `unsigned short`, to represent 260.

Answer (score 1):

> unsigned char Test = 260;

Because `260` is an integer literal your compiler should emit a warning. How to handle that? **Do not ignore compiler warnings** (or use an alternative syntax to avoid automatic conversions or enable this warning as error). Also note that integer literals are always positive (unsigned): `-1` is not an integer literal: it's i.l. `1` and unary operator `-`. For gcc I'd suggest to use `-Wstrict-overflow=2` (or more, according to your code policies) and possibly enabling `-Werror=strict-overflow`. For MS VC++ you may enable warning C4307 with `/we4307` and `/W14307` if you keep warnings at level 1 (!!!) (you may also do it with `#pragma warning` directive).

> How to detect overflow of unsigned char variable in c++?

At compile-time compiler warnings are your friends but at **run-time**?

There is not a portable way (like, for example, `checked` in C#) to do this and *better* technique depends on which type of operation you want to *monitor*. For a *simple* assignment (made with values known at run-time) you may write something like this:

```
int32_t bigNumber = 260;
uint8_t smallNumber = static_cast<uint8_t>(bigNumber);
if (static_cast<int32_t>(smallNumber) != bigNumber) {
    // Overflow...
}
```

In alternative you may check before assigning:

```
int32_t bigNumber = 260;
if (bigNumber > UINT8_MAX) {
    // Overflow
}
```

Note that you may also make compiler life easier writing (after assignment):

```
if (smallNumber != bigNumber) {
    // Overflow
}
```

It works because automatic promotions will convert `smallNumber` to `bigNumber` type (unless you're performing a signed/unsigned comparison, in this case you should simply avoid this alternative).

If you need it often you may write a small helper function to perform this *conversion*. For some ideas and possible implementations, if you're using MS compiler, you may take a look to `SafeInt` family functions (note, however, that in this case assignment and casting won't throw).

Comment: This might help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

unsigned numbers always positive between 0 to 255.and obey the law 2^n(n = numbers of bit in type);if char 8 bit then unsigned char variables have values between 0 and 255 , while signed chars have values between -128 and 127.

Comment: I guess, you meant `unsigned char` value to be in range 0 to 255 but even that is false: there is no constraint limiting the size of a `char` to 8 bits. There is only a requirement that `char` has at least 8 bits (and the number of bits in an `unsigned char` matches the number of bits in a `char`).

Comment: @SudipDas actually signed chars do not need to be in range [-128...127], range is implementation defined (note that not all architectures represent negative numbers in C2). That said how this answers the question?